# How to register a new PHP function in Twig?

Tags: 7, theming

I am trying to create a theme for Drupal 7 with Twig. If I wanted to register a new PHP function, I should implement "hook_twig_function()" as the [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/tfd7) explains.

My simple question is: where should I implement my functions? If I write code - as usual -  inside my "template.php", I have this alert: "*Unknown "my_module_coolfunction" function in "sites/all/themes/abc/templates/page.tpl.twig*"

If I edited the "Extension.php" file, after every update, I would lost all my custom functions.

Answer (score 1):

In the docs it says:

> #### Functions
>
> To register a new filter you should implement **hook_twig_function()** and
>   return an indexed array with unique keys and new Twig_SimpleFunction
>   as value.
>
> ```
> function my_module_twig_function(){
> ```

To answer your question:

> My simple question is: where should I implement my functions?

Notice how it uses "my_module", so clearly in your custom module **.module** file is where these function(s) should be added. If you don't have a custom module yet, then you will need to create one.

So if your custom module is named Hello Kitty, then in **hello_kitty.module**

```
function hello_kitty_twig_function(){
    $functions = [];
    $functions['coolfunction'] = new Twig_SimpleFunction('coolfunction','hello_kitty_coolfunction');
    return $filters;
}

function hello_kitty_coolfunction($param_1,$param_2...){
    // do what you need to do, and return something.
}
```